# CentOS or RedHat - search rpm DB metadata files

Tags: centos, redhat-enterprise-linux, rpm, dpkg

When I query installed packages on rpm based OSs (`rpm -q`), I assume it pulls the data from a then metadata files in **/var/lib/rpm/***. The files there seem in a binary format (rpm DB?).

I want to be able to search them myself. Without `rpm` or `yum` , similar to **/var/lib/dpkg/status** in Debian based OSs.

Any idea on how this can be done? Maybe convert the DB files to flat text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging around, I found that these files are stored in the Berkeley DB format.
To dump their content to a parseable text, I used the `db_dump` tool, which is part of the **libdb-utils** package.

You can see some details in this SO question: [examining-berkeley-db-files-from-the-cli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37644/examining-berkeley-db-files-from-the-cli)

I hope this helps.